# Proof of The Optimality Of Greedy Algorithm for The Interval Scheduling Problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization, greedy-algorithms, correctness-proof, induction

I have this proof for the optimality of the greedy algorithm for the interval scheduling problem in my algorithms class, but I'm struggling to understand it fully, especially starting from the second slide. Does anyone know how to simplify this proof explanation? Thanks!

[image: Third Slide]
[image: Second Slide]
[image: First Slide]

Comment: The idea is that if $a_{i_j}$ is the earliest activity that greedy chooses, but that it's not in the optimal solution $S$, then you could just kick out the earliest activity from $S$ that differs from greedy, and put $a_{i_j}$ in instead.  This would yield an alternate optimal solution.  By repeating this for every $a_{i_j}$, we eventually obtain an optimal solution equal to the one returned by greedy.  Is there any specific step in the slides that you are not sure about?

Comment: How are we guaranteed that S after kicking out an element from it will yield another optimal solution? Also, I'm mainly confused about the first 3 points of the second slide.